# MS-Access 2010: Subform event, form_load, triggered by DoCmd.GoToRecord

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a navigation form and a subform that uses the form_load event trigger.

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec
    CompanyID.SetFocus
End Sub
```

When it hits "DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec", it triggers the Form_Load event again and gives a "No Current Record" upon hitting the end. When I press Debug, it highlights "DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec". I can continue to run the code but then when it hits "CompanyID.SetFocus" I get Run-time Error '2467'. I just want it to open the form, ready to accept a new record.

Comment: Have you considered Open Form ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff820845.aspx ) with DataMode acFormAdd?

Comment: Thanks for the idea. Looks like I'll be abandoning the navigation form.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to edit existing records on the subform you could set the subform's `DataEntry` property to `True`.  This will hide existing records, essentially starting you off on a new record.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa224193(v=office.11).aspx

Comment: I'm making forms that do double duty: viewing/editing old records as well adding new ones.

Comment: Try using the `On Open` event instead.  It worked for me in a quick test database.